# Power BI Desktop Automatic Refresh

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have developed several reports in power bi desktop and published them to PowerBi.com. These reports are refreshed on daily basis manually. Is there any way that I can refresh the power bi desktop file i.e. .pibx file programmatically or can schedule it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install and configure the Power BI Gateway - Personal for this.  It supports scheduled refresh (up to 8 times per day).  It requires a Power BI Pro license.

Here's the details:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-personal-gateway/